# Why does my menu not go all the way to the left

Tags: html, css, outline

I'm new to coding so sorry if what I'm doing here is completely stupid.

I'm building a very basic website using html and css. I want to use 2 navigation bars. One on the top of the screen for the main navigatio. And one on the left side for navigating through that specific page.The first one works fine but the second one looks weird. The clickable links can't be moved further to the left and are therefore sticking out on the right. This is what I mean:

[image]

*I'm hovering with my mouse on "content2"*

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code I wrote:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar active" href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="page1.html">page 1</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="page2.html">page 2</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="page3.html">page 3</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="page4.html">page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="contentbar">   
        <ul class="ucontentbar">
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content1</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content2</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content3</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content4</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content5</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content6</a></li>
            <li class="contentbar"><a class="contentbar" href="#">content7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
    <p>text</p>

    </div>

</body>
```

And the CSS that goes with it:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

nav {
background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;

}

ul.navbar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: right;
position: fixed;
}

li.navbar{
float: left;
height: 60px;
}

a.navbar { 
display: inline-block;
padding: 19px 25px;
background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
text-align: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.navbar:hover {
background-color: black;
}

a.active {
background-color: rgb(80,80,220);
}

#contentbar {
background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}

ul.contentbar {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

li.contentbar {
list-style: none;

}

a.contentbar { 
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
color: white;
display: block;
width:300px;
height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;

}   

a.contentbar:hover {
background-color: black;
}

#page { 
background-color: rgb(0,200,100);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Without putting together a demo first, it looks like default margin and padding.

Comment: You may also want to set `overflow: hidden` on #contentbar. This will prevent it's children from overflowing.

Comment: .. or don't specify a width. The container has a width and it is unnecessary to give the children the same width. It will remain problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have a typo in the ul's classname `<ul class="ucontentbar">` so the padding is not being applied.

Answer (score 1):

give your `ul` to `padding: 0` or remove `width` style from `a.contentbar`.

by default, ul element has padding cause of its children. thats why your list seems like that.